# Difference in result of the same run due to python

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this question but since I wrote me code in python, I decided to ask here.

I am working with python on my linux machine and on spyder. On spyder there is version3.6. My ubuntu runs version 3.6.5. I ran my code on both but got different results despite copying the same code from spyder to my ubuntu.

Working Code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

b = ['3/', '2/', '3/0', '/0', '5/0']
c = [[7, 3, 0, 0], [5, 0, 5, 0], [0, 3, 7, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 8, 0]]
d = list(zip(b,[str(a).replace(' ','') for a in c]))

f =[]
for i in d:
    f.extend([i[0], (i[1]).strip("[]")])
g = [":".join(f[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(f), 2)]
h = list(map(itemgetter(-1), g))
k = []
for x in g:
    if any(int(i) >= 1 for i in h):
        y = x
    else:
        y = x[:-1].strip(',')
    k.append(y)
print(k)
```

Results are:

```
 ubuntu = ['3/:7,3,None', '2/:5,None,5', '3/0:None,3,7', '/0:10,None,0', '5/0:2,None,8']
 spyder = ['3/:7,3,0', '2/:5,0,5', '3/0:0,3,7', '/0:10,0,0', '5/0:2,0,8']
```

The result from spyder is the correct one. Why am I getting None's instead of zero with ubuntu version? I am pretty sure there is an underlying reason and hopefully someone can help me understand this. If not, what do I do to make the ubuntu result same as the one from spyder? Thank you

Comment: This is impossible to answer for us without seeing the code that produced the output.

Comment: Okay the specific code is so long. Do you think a small part of the code will help?

Comment: Yes, please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. That way we can help explain and fix the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with part of the code. I ran my code again and got the above result. I hope this will help because I am not sure why.

Comment: That’s.. a bit convoluted way of spelling `endidx = None if any(l[-1] for l in c) else -1; k = [f'{pre}:{",".join(map(str, post[:endidx]))}' for pre, post in zip(b, c)]`. I’ve reopened your question but I am somewhat skeptical anyone will be able to reproduce this as nothing in your code would randomly replace zeros with `None`.